# How do I scroll into a item in a list by search operation using react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, list, react-hooks

So, I made a react app that displays a list of items from a json file as in the pic. 
I want to implement a search feature where i can enter the name and it checks for the name in list and scrolls to it.

A person told me about scroll-into-view , but I'm not understand how to make it compare the search term to the names in list.

[image: App Pic]

My App.js code

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Notes from './Notes';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [notes] = useState([]);
  const handleSubmit= ()=>{
      //Upon submitting I want the search functionality to be implemented here . If thats the way to do it.
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className="App-header">  
        <form><input type="text" placeholder="Start Typing.." onSubmit={handleSubmit} ></input></form>
        <div className="pageTitle">Song Notes :</div> 
        <Notes thisNotes={notes}/>   
      </div>

    </div>
  );
  }

export default App;
```

My Notes.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
const Notes = ({notes})=>{
    const jsonNotes = require('./Notes.json');
    const songNotes = jsonNotes.map(note => {
        return(
            <div key={note.id}>
            <li class="noteAsList">

            <div className="songTitle">{note.Name}</div>

            <pre><br></br>{note.Notes}</pre>
            </li>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return(
        <div className="noteStyle">
          {songNotes} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Notes;
```

I'm looking to implement such a [feature](https://codepen.io/Natarajah/pen/mAGQpw). Either scrolling into view in the page or just displaying the item I asked for.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-mendel-ixh7d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
My App.js code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Notes from "./Notes";
import "./App.css";

const jsonNotes = require("./Notes.json");

const App = () => {
  const [notes] = useState([]);
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      const obj = jsonNotes.find(item => item.Name === event.target.value);
      const el = document.getElementById(obj.id);
      if (el)
        el.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: "smooth",
          block: "start",
          inline: "center"
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Start Typing.."
          onKeyPress={handleSubmit}
        />
        <div className="pageTitle">Song Notes :</div>
        <Notes thisNotes={notes} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My Notes.js code:

```
import React from "react";
const jsonNotes = require("./Notes.json");

const Notes = ({ notes }) => {
  const songNotes = jsonNotes.map(note => {
    return (
      <div id={note.id} key={note.id}>
        <li className="noteAsList">
          <div className="songTitle">{note.Name}</div>
          <pre>
            <br />
            {note.Notes}
          </pre>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="noteStyle">{songNotes}</div>;
};

export default Notes;
```

Comment: Just by copy pasting your code I get this 
    const el = document.getElementById(id);

Then by changing the 
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
to
    const el = document.getElementById(notes.id);

I get rid of the error , but it does not function.

My json format is this way though :

[
   {
      "id": 0,
    "Name": "YamunaiAatrile_DhaLapathi",
  "Notes" : " All the notes here "
   },
]

Comment: @harikrishnan id means your element id, that we have set in div

Comment: I'm more confused now. Could you tell me what id should I be giving there? I'm sorry but its confusing me.

I understanding you are telling the id given to div .. which is usually given as id="idName" .
But in this context , what do I use?

Comment: @harikrishnan can you please create a codesandbox and share here i will fix there, please all files means all ja and json files

Comment: Yes sure. I'm sorry for not being able to understand what you say. I'll create a sandbox now

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-moser-rs3rv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @harikrishnan checking

Comment: @harikrishnan please do check now

Comment: Link? I think you need to give me a new link with modified code. It is the same in the provided link

Comment: @harikrishnan if it helps please mark as answer and do upvote, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! That works. 
Instead of find() , What would I use to search based on partial inputs?
Right now..I need to write the full name of the song as it is. I would want it to search even with partial inputs,

And also, why OnKeyPress instead of onSubmit?

Comment: @harikrishnan Please also do upvote  
you can use any method you just need is id of that name where you want to scroll

Comment: @harikrishnan done some changes in handleSubmit function of App.js, please check , thanks

Comment: I checked, The problem with it is that, It scrolls as I'm typing and the search bar disappears . I would want the search bar to be fixed on top. 
Changing the search bar property to position:fixed , removes it from display

Comment: @harikrishnan so what is issue here ?, i see you problem is solved by `position:fixed `